# How to upload and fetch microsoft access database from server folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, upload, directory

I am using C# language.
I have to upload MS Access database to a folder on server and fetch the data from the uploaded database and display in GridView.
I am unable to do it.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            FileInfo f = new FileInfo(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            if (f.Extension.ToLower() == ".mdb" || f.Extension.ToLower() == ".accdb")
            {
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Pics/"+f.Name+ "" + f.Extension.ToLower()));
                string DBpath = Server.MapPath("~/Pics/" + f.Name);
                string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + DBpath + "";
                OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connection);
                OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from Table1", cn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Kindly provide some code what you have tried. [See how to ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: This isn't even a question.

Comment: what you want from us??? do you want to hire any developer to do this job for you???

Comment: It is giving error "Could not find file 'databsename',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my database is .accdb I had to use following connection string, the connection string in question is used for .mdb database only

```
string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBpath + "";
```